# Implementing classes using Generics

Tags: java, generics

I am kind a confuse on the implementation i am working on. This the method which i am suppose to call

`<I, O, T> T post(String url, I data, ContentBuilder<I, HttpEntity> contentBuilder, ResponseHandler<? extends T> responseHandler);`

Now i have to write couple of classes which will be used for ContentBuilder and responsehandler. the thing to be noticed is return type *T*.

I wrote an abstract class `WSResponse` and then extended it `MyWSResponse` so that my response handler looks like

`ResponseHandler <WSResponse> rh = new MyWSResponse();`

The method which is calling this **post** method has this signature

```
public interface GPCl{
   public <T> T callPost (String data)
}
```

...

```
public <T> T callPost(String data){
    HttpWebServiceClient client = getHttpWSClient();
    ContentBuilder<String, HttpEntity> contentBuilder = new MyXMLBuilder();
    ResponseHandler<WSResponse> rh= new MyWSResponse();

    WSResponse wsResponse = client.post("", data, contentBuilder, rh);
    return (T)wsResponse;
}
```

Now i am confused at **return** type of this method. Would it remain **T** or something else? If i change it from T to WSRespons, i get an error that i haven't implemented method `callPost`.

The method `callPost` is being called as

```
GPClient cl = new GPClient(myhttpParams);
cl.callPost(d)
```

P.S:
this is first time i am dealing with generics

Comment: Where is the method callPost(..) coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods of this type -- `<T> T method(things that don't mention T)` -- are almost never what you want to do, and are highly dangerous, because they inevitably involve casts that probably don't work -- but you won't be warned until it fails at runtime.  I *suspect* that the return type of this method should just be `WSResponse`, but your question isn't clear enough for me to be sure.

Comment: I can't change thing in the API which i am implementing. see my edit.

Comment: Um.  Okay.  That interface is really disturbingly dangerous, and you should complain.  Other than that -- there's nothing you can do besides the dangerous cast.

Comment: So i was right when i first pointed out this to the **senior** developer! Thanks for help :)